# How can I remove Ubuntu and install Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, ubuntu

I had a new hard drive and I immediately installed Ubuntu. Now I need to completely remove Ubuntu and install Windows 7 only.

I tried to set the BIOS priority to DVD but nevertheless Ubuntu is taking over and booting normally.

How can I get rid of it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure, that you have the right order? DVD before HDD... It is possible to change the order...